# Changing the display name of a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, macos-mojave

How can I change the display name of a file using Python?

**Details:**

- Using Mac OS X Mojave
- Python 3.7

To be precise, I want to **hide** the file extension of a file so that `textfile.txt` is seen as `textfile` only, **without actually removing** the file extension.

**EDIT:**
The display name of a file looks like this:

[image]

And I want it to look like this:

[image]

Comment: What's the "display name" of a file? Where are you displaying these?

Comment: I have no good answer, but this might provide some leads: https://superuser.com/questions/399899/show-hide-extension-of-a-file-through-os-x-command-line (TL;DR: probably use AppleScript, either by calling osascript(1) or by using NSAppleScript from PyObjC.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is

```
import os
print(os.path.splitext("/path/to/textfile.txt")[0])
```

The output will be

```
/path/to/textfile
```

**EDIT**:
from your last edit i figured that what you're looking for is to hide extensions directly in the OS using Python. Well, this is more a task to do modifying your system settings, i don't think that you will be able to change this type of system settings directly from Python.